# Remove border of checkbox in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, checkbox

I have used images for checkbox background,where image get change when checkbox is checked.It is proper in chrome but giving issue in Firefox. In Firefox it is showing border or box shadow for checkbox and also show black colour tick.

Screenshot of checkbox:

[image: Screenshot of checkbox]

```css
label {
  margin: 0;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 3px 20px 3px 40px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: block;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: contain;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: 0;
  margin: -4px 0 0;
  margin-top: 1px\9;
  line-height: normal;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 4px\9;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) {
  background-image: url(http://livemysite.com/Eduardo/img/unchecked.png);
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-image: url(http://livemysite.com/Eduardo/img/checked.png);
  background-size: 70%;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1">Test</label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
label.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {display:none;}
label.checkbox span {
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #BBB;
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:3px;
  transition:width 0.1s, height 0.1s, margin 0.1s;
  background-image: url(http://livemysite.com/Eduardo/img/unchecked.png);
}
label.checkbox :checked + span {
  width:27px;
  height:27px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-image: url(http://livemysite.com/Eduardo/img/checked.png);
  background-size: 70%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox"/>
  <span></span>Test
</label>
```

Comment: @supriya now check the above code. If any doubt let me know

Comment: @supriya Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, its not possible to remove borders on browser native checkboxes (it will not work in all browsers).
You can deal with appearance modifiers plus accurate css selectors appliing styles but it could not work sometimes.

```
-moz-appearance:none;
-webkit-appearance:none;
-o-appearance:none;
```